# How do I programmatically forward a users X509 certificate to another server?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, openssl, jruby, x509

I have a JRuby on Rails application deployed to Tomcat which is setup for two-way/mutal authentication using SSL. When a request comes in to my Rails application, it then makes a request to an external server. That external server requires the certificate of the person originating the request. I need to grab the certificate from my Rails app and forward it when making a request to the external server (another Rails app).

I can get the X509Certificate (java) object in a controller in the Rails app where the initial goes. I can then get the DER string (X509CertificateImpl#getEncoded, something like that) and I can build a PEM string if necessary...but how I can forward that on when making a request to the external Rails app?

I tried sticking the urlsafe base64 encoded PEM version into a header, but when I pull out that header on the external rails app it only appears to get a chunk of it (60 characters as opposed to the 2095 that were sent).

Any ideas/thoughts on how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

If the external server requires client-side SSL authentication and not just a certificate, then you are out of luck. The reason is that SSL autentication is performed using private keys, not certificates themselves. And private keys are not transferred to the server. So grabbing the certificate will give you nothing.